# し grammar question

Tags: grammar

The following sentence appears in my textbook.

> 山下先生はいい先生です。教えるのが上手だし、しんせつだし。

Is the second し at the end of the sentence necessary? Does it change the meaning to omit this second し? Does the second し imply that there could also be other reasons (which are not mentioned) why  山下先生 is a good teacher?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

し has two different functions:

1. Lists things with slight emphasis. The second し must *not* be added.

   > 彼は背が高いし足も速い。 He is tall and he can run fast.
2. Denotes a reason.

   > 遅くなったし、もう帰ろう。  It's already late, so let's go back.
   >   だって怖かったし。 Well, coz I was scared.

し often plays these two roles simultaneously. 「お金がないし時間もないし、どこにも行きたくない。」「もう帰ろうよ。暗いし、寒いし。」 The second し in each sentence can be replaced by ので, から, etc. 「お金がないし時間もないので、どこにも行きたくない。」

Anyway, sentence-end し is usually for denoting a reason. In your case, the final し marks a reason why 山下先生 is a good teacher, referring to the previous sentence. Even if you dropped it, the sentence is still understandable, but it's not "optional".